# LinearLayout new line instead of concatenate

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout

I find this a stupid question to ask but I seem to be unable to find the answer online. I want to add 2 TextViews to a LinearLayout and want them to show the result below eachother, not concatenate.

```
ll.addView(textview);
ll.addView(textViewReply);
```

shows:

```
HelloHello to you too!
```

while I want it to be:

```
Hello
Hello to you too!
```

I thought that a linear layout could only store one object per line. Can someone explain this? :-)

Comment: what is the orientation of your parent layout ? make it vertical from horizontal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL) before adding textview